# Symfony2 generate crud for third party bundle

Tags: symfony, admin, crud, vendor

It is possible to generate a basic admin interface using the CRUD generator for my Entities. 
i.e. `php app/console generate:doctrine:crud`

The question is, can this also be done for an entity bundled by a vendor? I get errors about not finding the entity I want.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you want to add extra functionality to the vendor bundle so you might need to extend it.

[Symfony2 Inhertiance](http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/cookbook/bundles/inheritance.html)

Comment: I think OP (Original Poster, the person who asked in short) wants learn about the additional entities (ORM) in Symfony2 bundles and to get it work with the CRUD generation feature, not Symfony2 inheritance in general. You probably can add about how it's configured/done to your answer to get it more on topic.